# How to change the slide transition speed using keen slider?

Tags: reactjs

There doesn't appear to be any option to change the animation duration when changing slides?

```
    const { slides } = data
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
    const [opacities, setOpacities] = useState([])
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
    const [sliderRef, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider({
    initial: 0,
    slides: slides.length,
    loop: true,
    slideChanged(slider) {
      setCurrentSlide(slider.track.details.rel)
    },

    created() {
      setLoaded(true)
    },
    detailsChanged(s) {
      const new_opacities = s.track.details.slides.map((slide) => slide.portion)
      setOpacities(new_opacities)
    }
  })
```